# Similarity measurement with wordnet?

Tags: java, wordnet

I'm using wordnet to calculate similarity measurement between two words. I'm using `edu.mit.jwi_2.1.4.jar` and `edu.sussex.nlp.jws.beta.11.jar` but when I calculate the words "apple" and "banana" by resnik measurement, it is 8,4. Why is it more than 1?

```
    public class test {
    String dir = "C:/Program Files (x86)/WordNet";
    JWS ws = new JWS(dir,"2.1");
    /**
     * @param args
     */
     public void testResnikSimilarity() {    
        Resnik jcn = ws.getResnik();
         System.out.println("Resnik");
         // all senses
         TreeMap scores1 = jcn.res("apple", "banana", "n"); // all senses
         //TreeMap scores1 = jcn.jcn("apple", 1, "banana", "n");
         // fixed;all
         //TreeMap scores1 = jcn.jcn("apple", "banana", 2, "n");
         // all;fixed
         for(String s : scores1.keySet())
         System.out.println(s + "\t" + scores1.get(s));
         // specific senses
         System.out.println("\nspecific pair\t=\t" + jcn.res("apple", 1, "banana",
         1, "n") + "\n");
         // max.
         System.out.println("\nhighest score\t=\t" + jcn.max("apple", "banana",
         "n") + "\n\n\n");
         }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To cite the [NLTK Documentation](http://nltk.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/howto/wordnet.html/):

> Resnik Similarity: Return a score denoting how similar two word senses
>   are, based on the Information Content (IC) of the Least Common
>   Subsumer (most specific ancestor node). Note that for any similarity
>   measure that uses information content, the result is dependent on the
>   corpus used to generate the information content and the specifics of
>   how the information content was created.

I don't know how to set the information content in JWS. In the NLTK you can do it as follows, using data from the Brown Corpus and the BNC:

```
ic = wordnet_ic.ic('ic-brown.dat')
banana.res_similarity(apple, ic=ic)
>>> 8.1703339116227411
ic = wordnet_ic.ic('ic-bnc.dat')
banana.res_similarity(apple, ic=ic)
>>> 7.9753635531935334
```

See also this [paper](http://www.jimdavies.org/summaries/resnik1995.html) for details.